# Performance evaluation

Tags: model, roc, auc, model-evaluation, rms

I'd like to test the performance of a penalized regression. I did three separate regressions for each response variable (one numerical, one binomial and one multinomial). I was checking this [link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/7-important-model-evaluation-error-metrics/), and I have a question: should I use a different metric for each type of response? Is this correct? Or should I use the same for all of them?

Comment: If you want to compare them then it needs to be the same metric.

Comment: @user2974951 not really. I'll probably compare the performance of various models for each predictor. So i'll go for ROC for the binomial predictor and RMSE for the numerical one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a form of mean-squared error to evaluate all 3 outcomes?

That's the obvious choice that you've already made for the numeric response variable.

For evaluating models of binomial or multinomial outcomes the [Brier score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score) is a type of mean squared error (based on squared differences between predicted probabilities of class membership and 0/1 values of actual class membership). The Brier score is a [proper scoring rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule#Proper_scoring_rules) that has advantages over ROC, which some call a [semi-proper scoring rule](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/339993/28500).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I didn't know about this aspect of ROC. I'll do as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate your model for the binomial and multinomial target visually, you can use the lift, gains and response plots. For details how to interpret them, have a look at this blog: [modelplot](http://modelplot.github.io). It comes with an r package as well as a python module.