# Prove that AUROC is an improper scoring rule

Tags: logistic, roc, scoring-rules

It has been stated in many places that AUROC is an improper scoring rule.But I haven't seen anyone proving it. Does someone have a working example that shows that maximizing AUROC actually moves away probability estimates from actual probabilities.

Comment: [Gneiting & Vogel (2018, arXiv:1809.04808)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.04808), in their footnote 4 note that AUC ignores calibration, referring to p. 346 in Wilks (2011), *Statistical  Methods  in  the  Atmospheric  Sciences*.

Comment: Take a look at [Byrne (2016)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ejs/1455715967), as cited in [this answer to the proposed duplicate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/339993/1352).