# MAE to find tuning parameter for lasso logistic regression

Tags: logistic, classification, cross-validation, regularization, sparse

I have a classification problem. The actual outcomes are binary (0 or 1), but I want to predict probabilities, rather than predicting simply 0 or 1. I also want something with feature selection, since there are a lot of predictors. One approach that I want to try is L1-regularized logistic regression (specifically [this implementation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.fit_regularized.html) in [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org)). One has to find a value for $\alpha$, the weight of the L1-regularization. I plan to do this in the following way:

1. Select some potential values of $\alpha$, say 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10 and 100.
2. Employ 5-fold cross validation: Fit the model on the union of the four training folds (using the [aforementioned method](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.fit_regularized.html)) and then calculate the mean absolute error (MAE) on the test fold. A toy example: If the actual outcomes in the test fold are [1, 0, 1, 0] and the predicted probabilities are [0.9, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7], then the MAE is 0.2 (= (0.1 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.7) / 4).
3. Repeat step 2. for each of the five cross-validation runs and then calculate the mean MAE. A toy example: If the MAEs of the cross-validation runs are 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3 and 0.1, then the mean MAE is 0.2 (= (0.2 + 0.1 + 0.3 + 0.3 + 0.1) / 5).
4. Repeat steps 2. and 3. for each value of $\alpha$ given in step 1.
5. Choose the value of $\alpha$ with the least mean MAE.

Is this a sensible approach? Is it theoretically sound or would an information criterion such as the AIC be better? There is [this nice guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_lasso_model_selection.html) from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html), but it is for linear regression, rather than logistic regression; in any case, they use the mean squared error. The AIC takes the number of parameters into account (the fewer the better), but the cross-validation approach does not. Since I want feature selection, I would be willing to sacrifice some predictive accuracy for the sake of having fewer features in the model.

To give a rough picture: The data contains approximately 120 features and 10000 rows. I have scaled the data. And to avoid any confusion: The approach uses the MAE only for hyperparameter tuning, not for the model fitting itself.

EDIT: Another potential approach would be calculate the likelihood of the test-fold predictions:

$$
\prod_{\text{outcome is 1}}\text{predicted probability} \; \times \prod_{\text{outcome is 0}}1 - \text{predicted probability}
$$

Would this be a better scoring method than the MAE?

Comment: Why use MAE instead of the crossentropy loss (log loss) or even square loss? [Absolute loss is problematic for probability predictions.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/473702/247274) $//$ Why do you want to use LASSO to zero-out features? Except in a narrow sense, LASSO doesn’t really do feature selection. You still consider many features but just estimate their effects to be zero.

Comment: By "feature selection" here I just mean having some coefficients set to zero. (I have already removed a number of columns prior to any model fitting.) The idea to use the MAE came from adapting the approach in _Introduction to Statistical Learning_, specifically equation (5.4) where the indicator function is used. I had completely overlooked the cross-entropy – thank you!

Comment: But why do you want those coefficients set to zero?

Comment: I want to interpret the model, so whittling down the features to those that are relevant would be helpful. Is feature selection not one of the advantages of L1-regularization or have I misunderstood?

Comment: LASSO definitely does tend to zero-out many coefficients. I [dispute](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/608454/247274) that this is feature selection (at least in a strong sense), since you still consider all of the features in your model training.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [the thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/473702/1352) Dave [links to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/608451/mae-to-find-tuning-parameter-for-lasso-logistic-regression#comment1129243_608451), minimizing the MAE will incentivize you towards biased "hard classifications": if 60% of samples with a given predictor configuration are of class A, then the MAE-optimal classification would be to predict a 100% (not 60%) probability of them to be of class A.

Minimizing the MAE is thus equivalent to maximizing accuracy, [which has major problems](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352).

I sympathize with your goal of [sparse probabilistic classification](https://www.google.com/search?q=sparse+probabilistic+classification), but minimizing the MAE is not the way to go about it.

Comment: Very clear. The log-loss would be a more suitable scoring method, right?

Comment: [We have a thread comparing different proper scoring rules here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/274088/1352) I personally am a big fan of the log loss. However, simply minimizing it will not give you a sparse model. Unfortunately, [we don't seem to have a useful thread on this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sparse+classification) - everything carrying both tags seems to consider "sparsity" about *predictors*, not the *model*.

Comment: I am confused then. How is one to find a value for alpha for regularized logistic regression?

Comment: You minimize the sum of the negative log-likelihood (which is just the log loss) and a scaled $\ell_1$ penalty on the coefficient vector, which gives you a sparse solution, see e.g., section 3.2 in Hastie, Tibshirani & Wainwright, *Statistical Learning with Sparsity*. Did you have that $\ell_1$ regularization term in mind? If so, you are all good, sorry, I may have misunderstood.

Comment: No need to apologise! To avoid confusion (and to move this out of the comments), I have posted [a new question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/608467).