# imbalanced classes: ROC_AUC vs Precision_Recall AUC

Tags: model-evaluation, unbalanced-classes, roc, auc, precision-recall

I am dealing with a highly imbalanced classes problem. Accuracy is of course not a good performance metric in such cases, So I want to calculate either `ROC AUC sore` or `AUC precision-recall score` but I'm not sure which metric among the two is better for assessing imbalanced classes model.

Answer (score 0):

Related: [What does it mean that AUC is a semi-proper scoring rule?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/339919/1352)

You should really be using a proper scoring rule. [More information can be found at the tag wiki.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info)

[Why is LogLoss preferred over other proper scoring rules?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/274088/1352) specifically presents arguments for and against the log and the Brier score, which are two of the most common proper scoring rules.