# Why is AUC so often use to compare performance of different models in churn prediction task?

Tags: classification, predictive-models, auc, metric, churn

I have to build model to predict churn and when reading related work on the internet I have realized that in most of the cases the AUC is used as a metric to compare different models. That's surprising to me because, in general I have used different metrics to access the performance of various classifiers.
Is there something that makes churn prediction so unique that applying AUC is a better idea than using other accuracy metrics? Or I'm simply missing something?

Comment: Interesting question and a +1. What metrics do you prefer?

Comment: I would know a perfect answer for Species Distribution Modelling (predicting probability of occurrence), this is my area, but that answer probably wouldn't apply to predicting churn....

Comment: I'm with @Dave: we can probably give you better answers if we know what metrics you would use instead. In the meantime, [What does it mean that AUC is a semi-proper scoring rule?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/339919/1352) may be enlightening.

Comment: Normally there is a business case where you eg want to prioritise those most likely to churn (ie ranking). personally I would go for logloss where you aim to get accurate probability, so that you can calculate expected loss from churning ...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. In general I prefer using metrics like precision, recall balanced accuracy or f1 score. In this specific case the main objective (as it is a real business case) is to identify the customers that will most likely churn.

Comment: Probability exactly measures the colloquial “likelihood” of an event.